# AADB2C trigger password change from SPA with custom policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, msal-react

I'm looking into implementing the [add password change policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-change-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) for my SPA. It all seems straight-forward, but I would like to trigger the password change popup from my React code which is using the *msal-browser* library. In the mentioned tutorial, in the [Run the policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-change-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#run-the-policy) section, there is no indication on how to trigger this from the application. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the authentication in react SPA by using Azure AD B2C policy as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-react-spa-app).

In this sample, you can configure the password change policy in similar way as profile edit.